# JSON to ObservableCollection to be used in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mvvm, uwp

I'm new to UWP, Visual Studio and MVVM. Right now I have a relatively simple application, where I wish to just display students and their courses. I'm storing all the data in an external database, and using Web Api with NewtonSoft JSON to deserialize the information.

I have two classes, "Students" and "Courses". Each Student has a List property containing Courses.

How can I get each Student's Courses-List from the API, and display them correctly?

**Students class (Model):**

```
public class Students {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Courses> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

**Courses class (Model):**

```
public class Courses {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML (View):**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:NewStudentViewModel x:Name="viewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<RelativePanel>
    <ListView 
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}"
        Name="StudentList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5 0 0 0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CourseName, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</RelativePanel>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class NewStudentViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public  NewStudentViewModel() {
        InitaializeDataAsync();
    }

    ObservableCollection<Students> students;
    public ObservableCollection<Students> StudentList {
        get { 
            return students;
        }
        set {
            Set(ref students, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StudentList));
        }
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Students>> GetStudendts() {
        if (StudentList == null) {
            HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await Client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50491/api/students");

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                var Jsonresponse = await Client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:50491/api/students");
                var StudentModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Students>>(Jsonresponse);
                return StudentModel;
            }
        }
        return StudentList;
    }

    private async Task InitaializeDataAsync() {
        StudentList = await GetStudendts();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set {

            _FirstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
        }
    }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName {
        get {
            return _LastName;
        }
        set {
            _LastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
        }
    }

    private string _CourseName;
    public string CourseName {
        get {
            return _CourseName;
        }
        set {
            _CourseName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CourseName));
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I'm able to only display the Firstname and the Lastname of the student, but I can't figure out how to display the Course-List for each Student. (It's enough to just display the name of the Course)

**PS (Bonus question):** My /api/Students returns this XML:

```
<ArrayOfStudents xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model">
    <Students>
        <Courses i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName>Olaf</FirstName>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <LastName>Roglebang</LastName>
    </Students>
    <Students>
        <Courses i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName>Winther</FirstName>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <LastName>Summers</LastName>
    </Students>
    <Students>
        <Courses i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <LastName>Bond</LastName>
    </Students>
</ArrayOfStudents>
```

Why doesn't it display the courses correctly?

**Edit 1:**
This is my result from api/Students in Json format :

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "sample string 2",
        "LastName": "sample string 3",
        "Courses": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "CourseName": "sample string 2",
                "CourseCode": "sample string 3",
                "Students": []
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "CourseName": "sample string 2",
                "CourseCode": "sample string 3",
                "Students": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "sample string 2",
        "LastName": "sample string 3",
        "Courses": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "CourseName": "sample string 2",
                "CourseCode": "sample string 3",
                "Students": []
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "CourseName": "sample string 2",
                "CourseCode": "sample string 3",
                "Students": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: The issue is in your API code. It is not returning the courses. First thing you should do is type the url of the API into a browser and make sure all the data you need is being returned. Once you have ensured that then move to the next part. Work on each part separately. Once that works then in your `InitaializeDataAsync` method create dummy data and see if your app can display the dummy data. Once that works then comment out the dummy data and call the API. Break your work into smaller units and work on each one and keep integrating it with the next unit and so on.

Comment: The error in the API is now fixed. I am now able to retrieve the data, but when I'm binding it to the view, it dispays for example "Winther Summers System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Model.Courses]", instead of "Winther Summers Calculus 370"

Comment: Could you please provide a sample jason value here when you call this `await Client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:50491/api/students")`?

Comment: Provided an example of the Json values returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your json sample value, I found that if you use this line `var StudentModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Students>>(Jsonresponse);` to parse json value, you would get a `Students` collection, then, in per `Students` object, it contains a `Coureses` collection. So, your xaml need to change like the following:

```
<ListView 
    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5 0 0 0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CourseName, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```